# Draw SVG Polygon from array of points in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, svg

if there is an array like this,(arr includes points)

```
arr = [ [ 0,0 ], 
             [ 50,50 ],
             [ 25,25 ], ];
```

i want to draw SVG polygon using this array.

At first, i think this code will be okay, but it isn't.

```
<polygon points="arr[0][0],arr[0][1] arr[1][0],arr[1][1] arr[2][0],arr[2][1]" style = "fill:lime; stroke:purple; stroke-width:3;/">
```

Please, let me know how to make polygon using array of points.
Make some example code, please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the SVG DOM to do this although a polygon where the points form a straight line doesn't display unless you set a stroke.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
var polygon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
svg.appendChild(polygon);

var array = arr = [ [ 0,0 ], 
             [ 50,50 ],
             [ 25,25 ], ];

for (value of array) {
  var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
  point.x = value[0];
  point.y = value[1];
  polygon.points.appendItem(point);
}
```

```css
polygon {
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg">
</svg>
```

Comment: Very helpful answer. 

One note that stumped me, make sure you create the point with the original svg object, not the polygon.